# Google embed API cb=gapi object error

Tags: javascript

I am following the tutorial on Google Embed API on following link
[Embed API](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/) but got following errors in the google sign-in: 
How to resolve this issue?

```js
bject {error: Object}error: Object__proto__: Object
cb=gapi.loaded_0:139 Uncaught #<Object>cb=gapi.loaded_0:139 (anonymous function)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved on Github. [Here's the link](https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/issues/51)